# The line is entered from the keyboard, duplicate each grate word

Tags: c++, string

The string is entered from the keyboard, various characters, you need to duplicate every third word. I figured out how to count spaces, how to delete even words, but I can't figure out how to duplicate every third word, I will be very grateful if someone can help. Important (the string can contain any characters other than line breaks, including spaces and tabs). I can provide some of my code in C++

```cpp
int main()
{    
    wstring s, a, b;
    getline(ws(wcin), s);
    int k = 0;
    int slovo, count = 0;

    int i = 0;
    while (s[i] == ' ' && s[i] != '\0')
        i++;
    slovo = 0;
    while (s[i] != '\0') {
        if (s[i] != ' ' && slovo == 0)
        {
            slovo = 1;
            count++;
            if (count % 3 == 0)
            {

                int pos = i + 1;
                while (iswspace(s[pos])) pos--;
                while (!iswspace(s[pos])) pos--;

                int len = abs(pos - i);
                if (s[i + 1] == '\0') len++;

                while (--len >= 0)
                {
                    for (int q = pos; s[q] != '\0'; q++)
                        a += s[q];
                    b += L"" + a;
                    s.insert(i - 1, L"" + a);
                    i += a.length() + 1;
                    a = L"";
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (s[i] == ' ')
            slovo = 0;
        i++;
    }
    wcout << L"\nРезультат: ";

    wcout << s;
}
```

Should work like this:

Input:

```
q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q10 q11 q12
```

Output:

```
q1 q2 q q3 q4 q5 q q6 q7 q8 q q9 q10 q11 q q12
```

Comment: You are definitely doing it the hard way. Do you know that you can read a word using std::string and the >> operator? `std::string word; std::cin >> word;` reads one space seporated word.

Comment: a string can contain any characters except a line break,
including spaces and tabs

Comment: What is a *grate* word?

Answer (score 0):

So many solutions :D

I prefere you tokenise the input string:

```
#include <regex>

std::regex regex(" ");
 
std::vector<std::string> out(
                    std::sregex_token_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), regex, -1),
                    std::sregex_token_iterator()
                    );
```